# connect SATA hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a Dell Studio 1535 laptop, I removed my HDD and added a SSD.

If I connect my old HDD with an eSATA -> SATA cable, computer does not detect it.

My cable:
I used this [eSATAp to SATA power](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Power-Over-eSATAp-eSATA-to-SATA-22-pin-Adapter-Cable-2-5-3-5-HDD-12V-5V-Power-/221154596607) cable.
[image]

I can hear the drive spinning up.

Sometimes Windows 7 also show errors:

[image]

I downloaded and installed these two drivers, but is the same.

Comment: Go into Disk Management (Right-click My Computer - Manage) and check if the hard-drive appears there.

Comment: There is only my master SSD disk, no other disk.

Comment: Go to `Control Panel` - `Device Manager` - Right-click on the `Disk Drives` node and select `Scan for hardware changes`. After that, check `Disk Management`.

Comment: 1) Is the external harddisk detected if you press F12 to get to the boot menu? (It should show up as a bootablel device and you should even be able to boot your old windows installation on the external HDD.  2) The drivers are not SATA related and this is wh nothing changed after you installed them.

Comment: When i pushed F12 in list is only my master C disk. I think, Windows trying detect my new hard disk ad SD card. Maybe is there problems?